# How to use UITextView text as mask to cutout background in swift?

Tags: swift, uitextview

It is easy to do a background cutout with a normal label, using the following code for example:

```
    var coloredBackground : UIView!
    coloredBackground = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
    coloredBackground.backgroundColor = .blue
    coloredBackground.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(coloredBackground)

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: coloredBackground.bounds)
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image")
    coloredBackground.addSubview(imageView)

    let label = UILabel(frame: coloredBackground.bounds)
    label.text = "stackoverflow"
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 30)
    coloredBackground.addSubview(label)

    imageView.mask = label
```

However I cannot seem to apply it to a UITextView

Here is the desired effect
[image]

Comment: your code is not showing a UITextView. how did you add it?

Comment: just replace the label with the text view that's what I tried